# Best way to use a plugin inside another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm wondering what is be the proper way to use a plugin inside another plugin. Which is basically importing it and using it after it is loaded.

I've seen some people use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and others [append the file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732068/how-to-include-an-external-plugin-inside-of-another-jquery-plugin-being-authored) to make it work in local paths.

But, is this the good way of doing so? It implies the plugin will not only be one `.js` file but will also contain another `.js` files for each of the vendor plugins used. (and therefor a folder with all of them very probably)

I would like to have only one `.js` file. Which would be the way of doing this? Just copying and pasting the code of the vendor plugins above my plugin code?

Isn't there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managing jQuery Plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233317/managing-jquery-plugins)

Comment: Tell people that "library X" is a dependency of your plugin. If they want to use your plugin, it's up to them to include a `<script src="/library-x.js"></script>` in their page. Your plugin *definitely* shouldn't be hauling in its dependencies with AJAX, and you certainly shouldn't distribute your plugin with all its dependencies copy-pasted into your own file. Would you copy-paste all of jQuery in the top of every one of your plugins? Obviously not. It's up to the consumer of your plugin to make sure its dependencies are met.

Comment: Ok, so i seems the only way is copying and pasting maintaining the plugin header and author. [I've been talking a look at a quite big plugin called `handsontable`](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js) and it seems that's what it does. (with `bootstrap-typeahead.js`, for example)

Comment: That's not the "only way", that's the **incorrect way**. Do not copy-and-paste dependent code. That is absolutely the worst way to solve this problem.

Comment: So what else do you suggest. Tell the users to import other files too? I'm just taking a look at one of the biggest plugin I know and it does it on that way.

Comment: If people tell the user to include a dependency, they need to be sure of defining which versions to use!